# Handling Browser Home button click event in Angular 7

Tags: angular7

I am using `Angular 7` and struggling to get browser home button click event.

Scenario:- When a user clicks on the Home button of the browser then I need to show confirmation message to the user asking if the user wants to save the changes or not. If `"Yes"` then the user will stay on the current page and if clicks `"No"` then redirect to the browser default page or may be route to some other page.

When I searched on google, most of the links I got are for browser back button which does not help in this scenario.

I have tried below solutions so far which are not working as It's unable to catch and hold of the handlers for Refresh and Home button.

```
1. 
        @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) 
          {
            event.returnValue = false;
          }



    2. 

        //check for Navigation Timing API support
         if (window.performance) {
           console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
         }
         if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
             confirm('This is performance Api');
             console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
         } else {
             console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
         }



    3. 
          this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
           if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
               //trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
              this.router.navigated = false;
              if (!this.router.navigated){
                 console.log(browserRefresh);
              }
               //if you need to scroll back to top, here is the right place
              window.scrollTo(0, 0);
           }
        });
```

Please help.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried your first approach, `HostListener`, and it worked ok for me in edge, chrome and firefox.

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: Hi, We are using Chrome version Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)  ,

Comment: For 1st approch it shows a default popup and shows 2 button Reload and Cancel. after clicking on reload it reloads the page where i want a custom behaviour i.e i should be able to route to some other route or perform some action. for e.g as we can do in canDeactivateGuard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the behaviour you are seeking is not possible. If it were possible to override the `beforeunload` default behaviour (or similar) then malicious sites could trick users into thinking they have left a page when they have not.

In fact, it used to be possible to customise the message shown, but this feature was removed (in 2016) to prevent such scams:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations?hl=en#remove_custom_messages_in_onbeforeunload_dialogs

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. This information will help me lot to learn new thing. Thanks again. :-)